# Connecting Mosquitto to the new Azure MQTT backend

Tags: azure, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

Recently Microsoft Azure has added a MQTT backend to its' services. 
This service uses [TLS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/#endpoints) do encrypt its traffic. 
**I can't connect between Mosquitto and the Microsoft Azure Cloud.**

I downloaded the server certificate with

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mytarget.azure-devices.net:8883 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/test.cert
```

And then tried to connect with mosquitto_sub

```
mosquitto_sub -h mytarget.azure-devices.net -p 8883 -d -t devices/Device1/messages/events -i Device1 -u "mytarget.azure-devices.net/Device1" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=snip&sig=snip&skn=snip"  --cafile /tmp/test.pem --insecure
```

However, the connection is never built. 
Mosquitto outputs:

> Client Device1 sending CONNECT
>   Error: A TLS error occurred.

I have previously successfully connected mosquitto over ssl to the Amazon cloud (although I got a certificate and Private Key for that). 
So I tried with adding client certificate/key, which I got from AWS, hopingg the error is that mosquitto does need those files too.

```
mosquitto_sub -h mytarget.azure-devices.net -p 8883 -d -t devices/Device1/messages/events -i Device1 -u "mytarget.azure-devices.net/Device1" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=snip&sig=snip&skn=snip"  --cafile /tmp/test.pem --cert certificate.pem.crt --key -private.pem.key --insecure --insecure
```

However, this didn't help and didn't change the error message.

I then looked in to the mosquitto code at github and found that the error is probably caused [on this line](https://github.com/iosphere/mosquitto/blob/79f3b57da5b5a4498bcbe1e97917ce3aff874245/lib/net_mosq.c#L379) by SSL_connect, which seems to be a openssl function.

Has anybody made mosquitto connect to the Microsoft Azure cloud or has any pointers where to look next?

**edit**:

I seem to be able to publish by tunneling the SSL over socat:

```
socat openssl-connect:mytarget.azure-dices.net:8883,verify=0 tcp-l:8884,reuseaddr,fork
```

And then connection on mosquitto to -h localhost instead of azure gets me:

```
Client Device1 sending CONNECT
Client Device1 received CONNACK
Client Device1 sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'devices/Device1/messages/events', ... (4 bytes))
Client Device1 sending DISCONNECT
```

It might be that something from the Azure Host is throwing of mosquitto.
Subscribing like this with mosquitto also works.

The problem with this approach is that the ssl-connection seems to be destroyed after the first (few) packet(s) and socat subsequentally complains with

```
E SSL_write(): Broken pipe
```

Comment: Does port **8883** opened ?

Comment: Yes, port 883 on *.azure-devices.net is open, I got the certificate and openssl s_client connected successfully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else searching for this. 
We finally managed to get it working with mosquitto_sub/pub:

```
mosquitto_sub -h mytarget.azure-devices.net -p 8883 -t "devices/Device1/messages/devicebound/#" -i Device1 -u "mytarget.azure-devices.net/Device1" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=mytarget.azure-devices.net&sig=snip&skn=snip" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ --tls-version tlsv1 -d -V mqttv311 -q 1
```

and for publishing:

```
mosquitto_pub -h mytarget.azure-devices.net -p 8883 -t "devices/Device1/messages/events/" -i Device2 -u "mytarget.azure-devices.net/Device2" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=bbvgathering.azure-devices.net&sig=snip&se=snip&skn=snip" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ --tls-version tlsv1 -d -V mqttv311 -q 1 -m "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
```

**Important** You have to send JSON-Data, everything else will get rejected (at least on our setup)!

**Note** Be adviced that you (seemingly) can't directly send from one device to the other. As this is contra the *Cloud* way. 
You'll have to configure a Connection in the cloud

Comment: using your mosquitto_sub example I get the "Error: A TLS error occurred." with socat I get:
I SSL peer cert subject: "CN = *.azure-devices.net"
I SSL peer cert issuer: "C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2"
I commonName "*.amqpws.azure-devices.net" does not match subdomain peername "arduhub.azure-devices.net"
I commonName "*.su.management-azure-devices.net" does not match subdomain peername "arduhub.azure-devices.net"
- which points me to the idea that the certificates are incorrect.. any ideas?

Comment: regarding my last comment, what worked for me was removing the "--capath /etc/ssl/certs/" and adding "--insecure". it is strange and I'm suspecting there are some problems with the azure IoT Hub, as I get intermittent errors form the arduino device i'm trying to connect to the IoT Hub.

Comment: Glad you could make it work. I also had problems with the certificate in the beginning. It might actually be on MS side(?)...
For your Arduino: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/bbvch/streetlightd, where me and a colleague are in the process of generating a c++ wrapper class for MQTT, AMQP and HTTP. Still a work in progress, althought I think now all three protocosl are (more or less) working

Comment: Cool stuff. We're working on a visual feedback device that can be controlled over internet. In case you're curious https://github.com/mishacucicea/RedAlert - can be used as a streetlight if need be :) ...

Comment: "echo -n | openssl s_client -connect mytarget.azure-devices.net:8883 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/test.cert" I see you using this line to download the certificate but how did you download  it to the /etc/ssl/certs folder

Comment: Note that the downloading of the certificate happened in the question, not the answer. If I remember this correctly the /etc/ssl/certs part was needed for dummy certificates and not for the actual certificate.
Alternatively try moving it to /etc/ssl/certs and as Radu Pascal has suggested also try adding the --insecure part. 
This question is half a year old, so things may have changed by now.

Comment: "Note Be adviced that you (seemingly) can't directly send from one device to the other. As this is contra the Cloud way. You'll have to configure a Connection in the cloud"
I think i have encountered this. How do i create such a connection?

Comment: I am able to send non-json data and see it reflect in device manager

Comment: @Deadolus: Is this example you have given still working for you now? I'm also trying to publish some messages to Azure but it rejects everything.

Comment: @user2699113 I have no way to verify if this still works. Sorry.