# Azure IoT Hub, push from device fails every time with connection closed, even using mosquitto_pub

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, mosquitto

Getting stuck from 2 days by now.

I have a embedded device that connects with MQTT DIRECT to Azure IoT Hub using SAS method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly

Basic connection is OK (otherwise I get connection refused)
But PUSH always fails and Azure closes connection and I cannot see any messages in Azure Iot Explorer Telemetry.

Subscribe is OK also, I can subscribe from embedded and receive messages, including from Explorer when I use C2D Messages.

I said to try with another client.
Thanks to this post, I configured **mosquitto_pub** for test purposes (sending messages)
[Connecting Mosquitto to the new Azure MQTT backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863841/connecting-mosquitto-to-the-new-azure-mqtt-backend)

```
.\mosquitto_pub.exe -h XXXXX.azure-devices.net -u "XXXXX.azure-devices.net/mydevice6" -P "SharedAccessSignature sr=XXXXX.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fmydevice6&sig=WA9qbn7Xa%2FQ%2F90CL7PgnNoD8AllWW757QvGJ3s2Ik2E%3D&se=1681536409" -t "devices/mydevice6/messsages/events/" -p 8883 -d -i mydevice6 -d -V mqttv311 -q 1 -m "{""key"": ""value""}" --cafile "DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem"
Client mydevice6 sending CONNECT
Client mydevice6 received CONNACK (0)
Client mydevice6 sending PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/mydevice6/messsages/events/', ... (12 bytes))
Error: The connection was lost.
```

Again, appears that **mosquitto_pub** works just fine, if I change device ID, signature, or others stuff, I immediately receive "Connection refused"

The behavior is exactly what I see on my embedded device, I receive ACK from server, appears that I am able to PUSH, but push where??? The connection shall remain online, instead, Azure it closes immediately.

I think this is some kind of stupid mistake, or some bad Azure configuration.

I did another test, this time, successfully, from C# (using SDL examples)
I created a small console app, with these parameters

```
static DeviceClient deviceClient;
static string deviceConnectionString = "HostName=XXXXXX.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=mydevice2;SharedAccessKey=xP+WyHL1quc4ax9pQ7Fc8oKuhs/0iC5dSKH2yUqIjzM=";

            MyData data = new MyData { Id = "Param", Name = "Value" };
            var serializeData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializeData));

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("Send Message: {0}", serializeData);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(commandMessage);
```

This time message can be seen in Azure IoT Explorer.

Now why my embedded device and mosquitto_pub appears that PUSH messages, but

- I cannot see them anywhere
- Azure immediately disconnects

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Being discounted when trying to publish implies that the user/client id is not authorised to publish to the topic in question. Are you sure the topic should end with a `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting the answer from Microsoft Q&A forums [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1235850/azure-iot-hub-push-from-device-fails-every-time-wi) for visibility.

The fix for the issue is to correct the typo in the topic. The topic should be `devices/mydevice6/messages/events/` instead of misspelled messsages

@Orfruit, please note that, if you plan to use any device routing or want to view the data in JSON format, you will need to append `application/json;charset=utf-8` at the end of the topic to send the message in JSON format.

Here is the format of the topic to apply JSON formatting `devices/{device-id}/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8`. Please refer the documentation [Sending device to cloud messages for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#sending-device-to-cloud-messages).