# Azure IoT hub and sending messages with mosquitto_pub

Tags: azure, iot

I'm trying to send some simple message with mosquitto_pub to Azure IoT HUB but faced some problems with authorization. I'm using following script:

```
mosquitto_pub \
-h xxxdev.azure-devices.net \
-u "xxxdev.azure-devices.net/xxxdev/?api-version=2018-06-30" \
-P "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxx.azure- 
devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fxxxdev&sig=YYYYY&se=1570866689&skn=ZZZZZZZ" \
-t "devices/xxxdev/messages/events/" \
--cafile ca.pem \
-p 8883 \
-i xxxdev \
-V mqttv311 \
-d \
-m 'message'
```

and after run this script I get following messages:

```
Client xxxdev sending CONNECT
Client xxxdev received CONNACK (5)
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Client xxxdev sending DISCONNECT
```

My questions are: What exactly does those messages mean? Is it because some parameter like password (given with -P param) is wrong?

I've generated SAS token with bash script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

Assuming that this bash script generates properly the password - what else could be the problem here? How to fix the problem?

Comment: have you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754485/mosquitto-sending-messages-to-azure-iothub and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device?

Comment: Yes, I've seen both, but probably I still missing something. Maybe I set "policyname" parameter in the SAS generating script to wrong phrase? I set it to "device"...

Comment: try generating the SAS token using the device explorer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#for-device-explorer

Comment: I used Visual Studio Code for generating SAS and now I'm able to publish to Azure iot hub. Thank you.